# SciChart: How do I control whether rollover axis labels are displayed

Tags: scichart

I have a chart with multiple modifiers that provide different behaviors on rollover. The chart used to have a vertical line that would show up on rollover. I was asked to get rid of it, which was easy:

```
<sci:RolloverModifier
       DrawVerticalLine="False"
```

but I noticed that the label that shows up under the X axis is still there.  I've tried to remove it, I didn't figure out how to do it.

I've examined some other graphs in the application, and found a similar one, which has the labels showing on both the X and the Y axis

[edit: image removed to prevent potential client IP issues]

I tried comparing the charts, and they do have different sets of modifiers, but I didn't find out what causes one graph to only have the graph on the X axis, and the other one on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you want is [RolloverModifier.ShowAxisLabels](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.ChartModifiers.TooltipModifierBase~ShowAxisLabels.html).

However, the screenshot you've posted looks like the CursorModifier. If you find out that the CursorModifier is adding the labels then you can either remove this modifier, or you can try a workaround like this one on the [SciChart Forums](https://www.scichart.com/questions/question/hide-one-of-two-cursormodifier-axis-labels) (which is 4 years old so may be out of date!)